# Custom Media player design to scale when width changed

Tags: javascript, css, html, fullscreen, media

I am having a Trouble with  this custom media player, Media player not functioning properly.

**I have 2 problems:**

When full-screen it goes back to the default HTML5 player

When i adjust the width of the video tag it throws all of the spacing out and ruins the player.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<title>Video/Audio</title>

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' />
<style type="text/css">

</style>

<script src='jquery.js'></script>

<script src='javascript.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('video').videoPlayer({
        'playerWidth' : 1,
        'videoClass' : 'video'  
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container" class="player">
    <video width="700" height="400">
        <source src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/icevideos/151014+Cathodic+Protection+of+Highways/151014.PETERBOROUGH.CATHODICPROTECTION.HIGH1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.player {
    background: grey;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 40px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    bottom: 4px;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.video {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.video:hover .player {
    opacity: 1;
}

.player .progress {
    width: 60%;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 12px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    font-variant: normal;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.player .progress-bar {
    background: #FF6600;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 0;
}

.player .button-holder {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
}

.player .progress-button {
    background: #00bdff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    text-decoration: overline;
}


.player [class^="buffered"] {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.player .play-pause {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 3em;
    float: left;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #fff;
    color: #00bdff;
    width: 4%;
    padding: 4px 0 0 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}

.player .play, .player .pause-button {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.player .play .pause-button, .player .pause .play-button {
    display: none;
}

.player .pause-button {
    padding: 5px 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 34px;
}

.player .pause-button span {
    background: #FF6600;
    width: 8px;
    height: 24px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.player .pause-button span:first-of-type {
    margin: 0 4px 0 0;
}

.player .time {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 425px;
    bottom: 3px;
}

.player .stime, .ttime {
    color: #fff;
}
.player .play:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
}

.player .play:active, .pause-button:active span {
    text-shadow: 0 0 7px #fff;
}


.player .pause-button:hover span {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
} .player .pause-button:active span {
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px #fff;
}


.player .volume {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 7%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 70px;
}

.player .volume-icon {
    padding: 1.5%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
}

.player .volume-icon-hover {
    background-color: grey;
}

.player .volume-holder {
    height: 100px;
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background: grey;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    top: -100px;
}

.player .volume-bar-holder {
    background: black;
    width: 20px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    margin: 15px auto;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.player .volume-button {
    background: #00bdff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.player .volume-button-holder {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px; 
}

.player .volume-bar {
    background: #FF6600;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.player .fullscreen {
    width: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.player .fullscreen a {
    width: 25px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #00bdff;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.player .fullscreen a:hover {
    background: #FF6600;
}

.player .volume-icon span {
    width: 20%;
    height: 23%;
    background-color: #00bdff;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 40%;
    color: #fff;
    left: 22%;
}

.player .volume-icon span:before,
.player .volume-icon span:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
}
.player .volume-icon span:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 1em solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right-color: #00bdff;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -2px;
    left: 10%;
    margin-top: -40%;
}
.player .volume-icon span:after {
    width: 10%;
    height: 4%;
    border: 1px solid #00bdff;
    left: 150%;
    border-width: 0px 0px 0 0; 
    border-radius: 0 50px 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
     transform: rotate(45deg);
     font-variant: small-caps;
 }

.player .v-change-11 span:after { border-width: 10px 10px 0 0; top: 0; }
.player .v-change-10 span:after { border-width: 9px 9px 0 0; top: 1px; }
.player .v-change-9 span:after { border-width: 8px 8px 0 0; top: 1px; }
.player .v-change-8 span:after { border-width: 7px 7px 0 0; top: 2px; }
.player .v-change-7 span:after { border-width: 6px 6px 0 0; top: 2px; }
.player .v-change-6 span:after { border-width: 5px 5px 0 0; top: 3px; }
.player .v-change-5 span:after { border-width: 4px 4px 0 0; top: 3px; }
.player .v-change-4 span:after { border-width: 3px 3px 0 0; top: 4px; }
.player .v-change-3 span:after { border-width: 2px 2px 0 0; top: 4px; }
.player .v-change-2 span:after { border-width: 1px 1px 0 0; top: 5px; }
.player .v-change-1 span:after { border-width: 0px 0px 0 0; top: 5px; }

.player .v-change-1 span:after {
    content: '+';
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    font-size: 20px;
    top: -6px;
    left: 25px;
    color: #00bdff;
}

/* ------- IGNORE */

#header {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#header #center {
    text-align: center;
}

#header h1 span {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 50px;
}

#header p {
    font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
}
#header h1 {
    color: #892dbf;
    font: bold 40px 'Bree Serif', serif;
}

#travel {
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    font-variant: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#travel a {
    font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #f9f9f9;
}

.container {
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
}

.logo {
    margin-top: 9px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
```

JS

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.videoPlayer = function(options) {


        var settings = {  
            playerWidth : '0.95', // Default is 95%
            videoClass : 'video'  // Video Class
        }

        // Extend the options so they work with the plugin
        if(options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }


        // For each so that we keep chainability.
        return this.each(function() {   

            $(this)[0].addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {

                // Basic Variables 
                var $this = $(this);
                var $settings = settings;

                // Wrap the video in a div with the class of your choosing
                $this.wrap('<div class="'+$settings.videoClass+'"></div>');


                // Select the div we just wrapped our video in for easy selection.
                var $that = $this.parent('.'+$settings.videoClass);

                // The Structure of our video player
                {

                $( '<div class="player">'
                    +'<a href="http://www.ice.org.uk" target="_blank"><img class="logo" src="http://www.cpdonline.tv/ice-events/mediaplayer/icelogo.png" height="20px"></a>'
                     + '<div class="play-pause play">'
                       + '<span class="play-button">&#9658;</span>'
                       + '<div class="pause-button">'
                         + '<span> </span>'
                             + '<span> </span>'
                       + '</div>'
                     + '</div>'
                     + '<div class="progress">'
                       + '<div class="progress-bar">'
                         + '<div class="button-holder">'
                           + '<div class="progress-button"> </div>'
                         + '</div>'
                       + '</div>'
                       + '<div class="time">'
                         + '<span class="ctime">00:00</span>' 
                         + '<span class="stime"> / </span>'
                         + '<span class="ttime">00:00</span>'
                       + '</div>'
                     + '</div>'
                     + '<div class="volume">'
                       + '<div class="volume-holder">'
                         + '<div class="volume-bar-holder">'
                           + '<div class="volume-bar">'
                             + '<div class="volume-button-holder">' 
                               + '<div class="volume-button"> </div>'
                             + '</div>'
                           + '</div>'
                         + '</div>'
                       + '</div>'
                       + '<div class="volume-icon v-change-0">'
                         + '<span> </span>'
                       + '</div>'
                     + '</div>'
                     + '<div class="fullscreen"> '
                       + '<a href="#"> </a>'
                     + '</div>'
                   + '</div>').appendTo($that);

                }


                // Width of the video
                $videoWidth = $this.width();
                $that.width($videoWidth+'px');

                // Set width of the player based on previously noted settings
                $that.find('.player').css({'width' : ($settings.playerWidth*100)+'%', 'left' : ((100-$settings.playerWidth*100)/2)+'%'});


                // Video information
                var $spc = $(this)[0], // Specific video
                    $duration = $spc.duration, // Video Duration
                    $volume = $spc.volume, // Video volume
                    currentTime;

                // Some other misc variables to check when things are happening
                var $mclicking = false, 
                    $vclicking = false, 
                    $vidhover = false,
                    $volhover = false, 
                    $playing = false, 
                    $drop = false,
                    $begin = false,
                    $draggingProgess = false,
                    $storevol,  
                    x = 0, 
                    y = 0, 
                    vtime = 0, 
                    updProgWidth = 0, 
                    volume = 0;

                // Setting the width, etc of the player
                var $volume = $spc.volume;

                // So the user cant select text in the player
                $that.bind('selectstart', function() { return false; });

                // Set some widths
                var progWidth = $that.find('.progress').width();


                var bufferLength = function() {

                    // The buffered regions of the video
                    var buffered = $spc.buffered;

                    // Rest all buffered regions everytime this function is run
                    $that.find('[class^=buffered]').remove();

                    // If buffered regions exist
                    if(buffered.length > 0) {

                        // The length of the buffered regions is i
                        var i = buffered.length;

                        while(i--) {
                            // Max and min buffers
                            $maxBuffer = buffered.end(i);
                            $minBuffer = buffered.start(i);

                            // The offset and width of buffered area                
                            var bufferOffset = ($minBuffer / $duration) * 100;          
                            var bufferWidth = (($maxBuffer - $minBuffer) / $duration) * 100;

                            // Append the buffered regions to the video
                            $('<div class="buffered"></div>').css({"left" : bufferOffset+'%', 'width' : bufferWidth+'%'}).appendTo($that.find('.progress'));

                        }
                    }
                } 

                // Run the buffer function
                bufferLength();

                // The timing function, updates the time.
                var timeUpdate = function($ignore) {

                    // The current time of the video based on progress bar position
                    var time = Math.round(($('.progress-bar').width() / progWidth) * $duration);

                    // The 'real' time of the video
                    var curTime = $spc.currentTime;

                    // Seconds are set to 0 by default, minutes are the time divided by 60
                    // tminutes and tseconds are the total mins and seconds.
                    var seconds = 0,
                        minutes = Math.floor(time / 60),
                        tminutes = Math.round($duration / 60),
                        tseconds = Math.round(($duration) - (tminutes*60));

                    // If time exists (well, video time)
                    if(time) {
                        // seconds are equal to the time minus the minutes
                        seconds = Math.round(time) - (60*minutes);

                        // So if seconds go above 59
                        if(seconds > 59) {
                            // Increase minutes, reset seconds
                            seconds = Math.round(time) - (60*minutes);
                            if(seconds == 60) {
                                minutes = Math.round(time / 60); 
                                seconds = 0;
                            }
                        }

                    } 

                    // Updated progress width
                    updProgWidth = (curTime / $duration) * progWidth

                    // Set a zero before the number if its less than 10.
                    if(seconds < 10) { seconds = '0'+seconds; }
                    if(tseconds < 10) { tseconds = '0'+tseconds; }

                    // A variable set which we'll use later on
                    if($ignore != true) {
                        $that.find('.progress-bar').css({'width' : updProgWidth+'px'});
                        $that.find('.progress-button').css({'left' : (updProgWidth-$that.find('.progress-button').width())+'px'});
                    }

                    // Update times
                    $that.find('.ctime').html(minutes+':'+seconds) 
                    $that.find('.ttime').html(tminutes+':'+tseconds);

                    // If playing update buffer value
                    if($spc.currentTime > 0 && $spc.paused == false && $spc.ended == false) {
                        bufferLength();
                    }

                }

                // Run the timing function twice, once on init and again when the time updates.
                timeUpdate();
                $spc.addEventListener('timeupdate', timeUpdate);

                // When the user clicks play, bind a click event    
                $that.find('.play-pause').bind('click', function() {

                    // Set up a playing variable
                    if($spc.currentTime > 0 && $spc.paused == false && $spc.ended == false) {
                        $playing = false;
                    } else { $playing = true; }

                    // If playing, etc, change classes to show pause or play button
                    if($playing == false) {
                        $spc.pause();
                        $(this).addClass('play').removeClass('pause');
                        bufferLength();
                    } else {
                        $begin = true;
                        $spc.play();
                        $(this).addClass('pause').removeClass('play');
                    }               

                });


                // Bind a function to the progress bar so the user can select a point in the video
                $that.find('.progress').bind('mousedown', function(e) {

                    // Progress bar is being clicked
                    $mclicking = true;

                    // If video is playing then pause while we change time of the video
                    if($playing == true) {
                        $spc.pause();
                    }

                    // The x position of the mouse in the progress bar 
                    x = e.pageX - $that.find('.progress').offset().left;

                    // Update current time
                    currentTime = (x / progWidth) * $duration;

                    $spc.currentTime = currentTime;

                });

                // When the user clicks on the volume bar holder, initiate the volume change event
                $that.find('.volume-bar-holder').bind('mousedown', function(e) {

                    // Clicking of volume is true
                    $vclicking = true;

                    // Y position of mouse in volume slider
                    y = $that.find('.volume-bar-holder').height() - (e.pageY - $that.find('.volume-bar-holder').offset().top);

                    // Return false if user tries to click outside volume area
                    if(y < 0 || y > $(this).height()) {
                        $vclicking = false;
                        return false;
                    }

                    // Update CSS to reflect what's happened
                    $that.find('.volume-bar').css({'height' : y+'px'});
                    $that.find('.volume-button').css({'top' : (y-($that.find('.volume-button').height()/2))+'px'});

                    // Update some variables
                    $spc.volume = $that.find('.volume-bar').height() / $(this).height();
                    $storevol = $that.find('.volume-bar').height() / $(this).height();
                    $volume = $that.find('.volume-bar').height() / $(this).height();

                    // Run a little animation for the volume icon.
                    volanim();

                });

                // A quick function for binding the animation of the volume icon
                var volanim = function() {

                    // Check where volume is and update class depending on that.
                    for(var i = 0; i < 1; i += 0.1) {

                        var fi = parseInt(Math.floor(i*10)) / 10;
                        var volid = (fi * 10)+1;

                        if($volume == 1) {
                            if($volhover == true) {
                                $that.find('.volume-icon').removeClass().addClass('volume-icon volume-icon-hover v-change-11');
                            } else {
                                $that.find('.volume-icon').removeClass().addClass('volume-icon v-change-11');
                            }
                        }
                        else if($volume == 0) {
                            if($volhover == true) {
                                $that.find('.volume-icon').removeClass().addClass('volume-icon volume-icon-hover v-change-1');
                            } else {
                                $that.find('.volume-icon').removeClass().addClass('volume-icon v-change-1');
                            }
                        }
                        else if($volume > (fi-0.1) && volume < fi && !$that.find('.volume-icon').hasClass('v-change-'+volid)) {
                            if($volhover == true) {
                                $that.find('.volume-icon').removeClass().addClass('volume-icon volume-icon-hover v-change-'+volid); 
                            } else {
                                $that.find('.volume-icon').removeClass().addClass('volume-icon v-change-'+volid);   
                            }
                        }       

                    }
                }
                // Run the volanim function
                volanim();

                // Check if the user is hovering over the volume button
                $that.find('.volume').hover(function() {
                    $volhover = true;
                }, function() {
                    $volhover = false;
                });


                // For usability purposes then bind a function to the body assuming that the user has clicked mouse
                // down on the progress bar or volume bar
                $('body, html').bind('mousemove', function(e) {

                    // Hide the player if video has been played and user hovers away from video
                    if($begin == true) {
                        $that.hover(function() {
                            $that.find('.player').stop(true, false).animate({'opacity' : '1'}, 0.5);
                        }, function() {
                            $that.find('.player').stop(true, false).animate({'opacity' : '0'}, 0.5);
                        });
                    }

                    // For the progress bar controls
                    if($mclicking == true) {    

                        // Dragging is happening
                        $draggingProgress = true;
                        // The thing we're going to apply to the CSS (changes based on conditional statements);
                        var progMove = 0;
                        // Width of the progress button (a little button at the end of the progress bar)
                        var buttonWidth = $that.find('.progress-button').width();

                        // Updated x posititon the user is at
                        x = e.pageX - $that.find('.progress').offset().left;

                        // If video is playing
                        if($playing == true) {
                            // And the current time is less than the duration               
                            if(currentTime < $duration) {       
                                // Then the play-pause icon should definitely be a pause button 
                                $that.find('.play-pause').addClass('pause').removeClass('play');
                            }
                        }


                        if(x < 0) { // If x is less than 0 then move the progress bar 0px
                            progMove = 0;
                            $spc.currentTime = 0;
                        } 
                        else if(x > progWidth) { // If x is more than the progress bar width then set progMove to progWidth
                            $spc.currentTime = $duration;
                            progMove = progWidth;   
                        }
                        else { // Otherwise progMove is equal to the mouse x coordinate
                            progMove = x;
                            currentTime = (x / progWidth) * $duration;
                            $spc.currentTime = currentTime; 
                        }

                        // Change CSS based on previous conditional statement
                        $that.find('.progress-bar').css({'width' : $progMove+'px'});
                        $that.find('.progress-button').css({'left' : ($progMove-buttonWidth)+'px'});

                    }

                    // For the volume controls
                    if($vclicking == true) {    

                        // The position of the mouse on the volume slider
                        y = $that.find('.volume-bar-holder').height() - (e.pageY - $that.find('.volume-bar-holder').offset().top);

                        // The position the user is moving to on the slider.
                        var volMove = 0;

                        // If the volume holder box is hidden then just return false
                        if($that.find('.volume-holder').css('display') == 'none') {
                            $vclicking = false;
                            return false;
                        }

                        // Add the hover class to the volume icon
                        if(!$that.find('.volume-icon').hasClass('volume-icon-hover')) {
                            $that.find('.volume-icon').addClass('volume-icon-hover');
                        }


                        if(y < 0 || y == 0) { // If y is less than 0 or equal to 0 then volMove is 0.

                            $volume = 0; 
                            volMove = 0;

                            $that.find('.volume-icon').removeClass().addClass('volume-icon volume-icon-hover v-change-11');

                        } else if(y > $(this).find('.volume-bar-holder').height() || (y / $that.find('.volume-bar-holder').height()) == 1) { // If y is more than the height then volMove is equal to the height

                            $volume = 1; 
                            volMove = $that.find('.volume-bar-holder').height();

                            $that.find('.volume-icon').removeClass().addClass('volume-icon volume-icon-hover v-change-1');

                        } else { // Otherwise volMove is just y

                            $volume = $that.find('.volume-bar').height() / $that.find('.volume-bar-holder').height();
                            volMove = y;

                        }

                        // Adjust the CSS based on the previous conditional statmeent
                        $that.find('.volume-bar').css({'height' : volMove+'px'});
                        $that.find('.volume-button').css({'top' : (volMove+$that.find('.volume-button').height())+'px'});

                        // Run the animation function
                        volanim();

                        // Change the volume and store volume
                        // Store volume is the volume the user last had in place
                        // in case they want to mute the video, unmuting will then
                        // return the user to their previous volume.
                        $spc.volume = $volume;
                        $storevol = $volume;


                    }

                    // If the user hovers over the volume controls, then fade in or out the volume
                    // icon hover class

                    if($volhover == false) {

                        $that.find('.volume-holder').stop(true, false).fadeOut(100);
                        $that.find('.volume-icon').removeClass('volume-icon-hover');    

                    }

                    else {
                        $that.find('.volume-icon').addClass('volume-icon-hover');
                        $that.find('.volume-holder').fadeIn(100);           
                    }


                })  

                // When the video ends the play button becomes a pause button
                $spc.addEventListener('ended', function() {

                    $playing = false;

                    // If the user is not dragging
                    if($draggingProgress == false) {
                        $that.find('.play-pause').addClass('play').removeClass('pause');
                    }

                });

                // If the user clicks on the volume icon, mute the video, store previous volume, and then
                // show previous volume should they click on it again.
                $that.find('.volume-icon').bind('mousedown', function() {

                    $volume = $spc.volume; // Update volume

                    // If volume is undefined then the store volume is the current volume
                    if(typeof $storevol == 'undefined') {
                         $storevol = $spc.volume;
                    }

                    // If volume is more than 0
                    if($volume > 0) {
                        // then the user wants to mute the video, so volume will become 0
                        $spc.volume = 0; 
                        $volume = 0;
                        $that.find('.volume-bar').css({'height' : '0'});
                        volanim();
                    }
                    else {
                        // Otherwise user is unmuting video, so volume is now store volume.
                        $spc.volume = $storevol;
                        $volume = $storevol;
                        $that.find('.volume-bar').css({'height' : ($storevol*100)+'%'});
                        volanim();
                    }


                });


                // If the user lets go of the mouse, clicking is false for both volume and progress.
                // Also the video will begin playing if it was playing before the drag process began.
                // We're also running the bufferLength function
                $('body, html').bind('mouseup', function(e) {

                    $mclicking = false;
                    $vclicking = false;
                    $draggingProgress = false;

                    if($playing == true) {  
                        $spc.play();
                    }

                    bufferLength();


                });

                // Check if fullscreen supported. If it's not just don't show the fullscreen icon.
                if(!$spc.requestFullscreen && !$spc.mozRequestFullScreen && !$spc.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                    $('.fullscreen').hide();
                }

                // Requests fullscreen based on browser.
                $('.fullscreen').click(function() {

                    if ($spc.requestFullscreen) {
                        $spc.requestFullscreen();
                    }

                    else if ($spc.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                        $spc.mozRequestFullScreen();
                    }

                    else if ($spc.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                        $spc.webkitRequestFullScreen();
                    }

                });



            });

        });

    }

})(jQuery);
```

I would also like to point out that this is someone else source code and cannot find where i got this from.

https://jsfiddle.net/f39huqpv/

Comment: add this demo link in your Q -- https://jsfiddle.net/f39huqpv/